# xindy with AUCTeX

Tags: auctex, xindy

Is there a way to seamlessly integrate xindy with AUCTeX so that if I execute `C-c C-c` repeatedly (or alternatively if I execute `C-c C-a` once) the AUCTex engine will know the sequence of commands required to eventually produce a PDF file of my .tex source, including indices?

---

Consider the following LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{x}{name={world},description={the universe}}

\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\maketitle

Hello, \gls{x}!

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

If I run the following sequence, the resulting document doesn't contain a glossary (see below). Why? How can it be fixed?

1. `C-c Latex`
2. `C-c Xindy`
3. `C-c Latex`
4. `C-c View`

The resulting pdf file:

[image: Resulting pdf file shows no glossary.]

Comment: AUCTeX supports `xindy`, but doesn't know when it has to run it.  Ask the author of the package to issue a warning when it's necessary to run `xindy`, so that AUCTeX will be able to catch the warning and run the program appropriately.

Comment: @giordano: In what sense does AUCTeX support xindy? In the present state of things (given that xindy does not issue the necessary warnings) what is the recommended sequence of steps I need to follow to produce a xindy-indexed pdf file from a .tex source using AUCTeX?

Comment: @giordano Perhaps some local variable to set?

Comment: `xindy` is supported in the sense that it is in the list of commands that you can manually run with C-c C-c

Comment: @giordano: I've added an example document that seems to indicate that AUCTex doesn't support xindy.

Comment: Uhm, the command that is executed is `texindy filename-without-extension`, but probably that's wrong.  It can be adjusted, but I don't know how, the manual of `xindy` isn't particularly illuminating.  On which file you should run `texindy` on?

Comment: @giordano: According to [the glossaries package's guide for beginners](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf) (see list item 5 on p. 12), the command to run is `xindy -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M myDoc -t myDoc.glg -o myDoc.gls myDoc.glo`, where `myDoc` is the base name of the LaTeX document file. Alternatively (ibid. p. 12, the paragraph following list item 6), the following command can be run on the .aux file: `makeglossaries myDoc`.

Comment: Really?!? :-D I was looking to the manual with `man texindy`, that's why I couldn't find the information.  Anyway, you should customize `TeX-command-list` with `customize-variable RET TeX-command-list RET` and change the "Xindy" command with `xindy -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M %s -t %s.glg -o %s.gls %s.glo`, then click on the "Apply and save button".

Comment: @giordano: Thanks, it works. Is there a way to indicate a default sequence, so I can execute `C-c C-a`, or alternatively execute a sequence of `C-c C-c` without choosing the commands explicitly?

Comment: Yes, should be doable!  I'll try to write down an answer later ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AUCTeX has an entry for Xindy in [`TeX-command-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Commands) since 2013, but probably no one ever used it, since it seems it's wrong.

It turned out that the OP wanted to run the command

```
xindy -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M myDoc -t myDoc.glg -o myDoc.gls myDoc.glo
```

being `myDoc` the base name of the TeX file.

It's possible to customize the entry for Xindy in `TeX-command-list`.  One is by using `customize-variable` and is described in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369806/xindy-with-auctex#comment913075_369806), the other one, slightly better, is the following: add the following line to your init file:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(setf (cadr (assoc "Xindy" TeX-command-list))
         "xindy -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M %s -t %s.glg -o %s.gls %s.glo"))
```

AUCTeX offers the possibility to create a custom sequence of command to run.  For example, you can bind the sequence LaTeX - Xindy - LaTeX - View to the <kbd>C-c a</kbd> with the following code added to your init file:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c a")
     (lambda ()
       (interactive)
       (TeX-command-sequence '("LaTeX" "Xindy" "LaTeX" "View") t))))
```

It should be easy to adapt this code to your needs (change the keyboard shortcut or the sequence).