# glossaries-extra causes a "Package xkeyval Error: value `none' is not allowed." error

Tags: errors, xkeyval, glossaries-extra

The following LaTeX manuscript is copy-and-pasted from pp. 5-6 of Nicola L.C. Talbot's "The glossaries package v4.34: a guide for beginners", v. 2017-11-03 ([link](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort=none]{glossaries-extra}
\newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},plural={potatoes},
description={starchy tuber}}
\newglossaryentry{cabbage}{name={cabbage},
description={vegetable with thick green or purple leaves}}
\newglossaryentry{turnip}{name={turnip},
description={round pale root vegetable}}
\newglossaryentry{carrot}{name={carrot},
description={orange root}}
\begin{document}
Chop the \gls{cabbage}, \glspl{potato} and \glspl{carrot}.
\printunsrtglossaries % list all entries
\end{document}
```

When I compile it with `pdflatex`, the compilation fails with the following error message:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: value `none' is not allowed.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.784 \RequirePackage
                     {glossaries-compatible-307}
```

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

---

As per [egreg's request](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401211/glossaries-extra-causes-a-package-xkeyval-error-value-none-is-not-allowed#comment999168_401211), here's `\listfiles`'s output.

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
glossaries-extra.sty    2017/05/10 v1.15 (NLCT)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
glossaries.sty    2017/01/19 v4.29 (NLCT)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
mfirstuc.sty    2016/07/31 v2.04 (NLCT)
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
    xfor.sty    2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
datatool-base.sty    2016/07/28 v2.27 (NLCT)
 amsmath.sty    2016/11/05 v2.16a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  substr.sty    2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
datatool-fp.sty    2016/07/28 v2.27 (NLCT)
      fp.sty    1995/04/02
defpattern.sty    1994/10/12
fp-basic.sty    1996/05/13
fp-addons.sty    1995/03/15
 fp-snap.sty    1995/04/05
  fp-exp.sty    1995/04/03
fp-trigo.sty    1995/04/14
  fp-pas.sty    1994/08/29
fp-random.sty    1995/02/23
  fp-eqn.sty    1995/04/03
  fp-upn.sty    1996/10/21
 fp-eval.sty    1995/04/03
glossaries-compatible-307.sty    2017/01/19 v4.29 (NLCT)
glossary-hypernav.sty    2017/01/19 v4.29 (NLCT)
glossary-list.sty    2017/01/19 v4.29 (NLCT)
glossary-long.sty    2017/01/19 v4.29 (NLCT)
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
glossary-super.sty    2017/01/19 v4.29 (NLCT)
supertabular.sty    2004/02/20 v4.1e the supertabular environment
glossary-tree.sty    2017/01/19 v4.29 (NLCT)
 ***********
```

Comment: @egreg: What do you mean? Should I add the control-sequence `\listfiles` immediate after `\documentclass{article}`, and then recompile?

Comment: @egreg: OK, I've added `\listfiles` at the very beginning, and recompiled. Do you want me to copy-and-paste the list of files that precedes the error message I cited above?

Comment: @egreg: The log file does not contain the string `*File List*`, and there's no list of files following the error message.

Comment: @egreg: I see. I've edited my post with `\listfiles`'s output.

Comment: First update the `glossaries` bundle. I have `glossaries-extra` v. 1.23 and `glossaries` v. 4.34.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of `glossaries` is too old. The `sort=none` option was introduced to `glossaries` v4.30 (2017-06-11), so you need to update if you want to use it.

Comment: Incidentally, does `bib2gls` work with AUCTeX in the sense that running `pdflatex` on a LaTeX source file that contains `\usepackage{glossaries-extra}` emits whatever signal is necessary so that executing `C-c C-c` repeatedly in Emacs will run `pdflatex` -> `bib2gls` -> `pdflatex`?

Comment: @EvanAad I'm sorry I don't know anything about AUCTeX. Can it be configured to search for strings in the `.aux` file? If so, it needs to check for `\glsxtr@resource`.

Comment: To work with AUCTeX your package needs to issue a warning. See [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369806/xindy-with-auctex#comment913024_369806) from AUCTeX's author and maintainer.

Comment: @EvanAad There will be undefined references on the first run or when new references are added, but there's no way for LaTeX to determine if the number lists need updating on subsequent runs. (With `makeglossaries` there aren't any warnings at all.) How does AUCTeX deal with `makeindex` which also doesn't generate warnings.

Comment: I have no idea.